# Program Specific OpenGL Runtime Bug: Multiple Input Buffers For Skinned Animation

Tags: c++, opengl, animation, runtime, shader

**The Problem:**

It seems as if the second GLuint buffer is not being read in properly.

**Update:** So the problem must be when I try to input the data to the shader. I rewrote the code (the old code is still below) to use swizzling for the index parameter. That was the only way I could get it to work. I would like to use multiple glVertexAttribPointer's, but every time I try to gives me the same undefined results.

**What I Am Trying To Do:**

I'm testing out very simple skinned animation with a very simplified shader,

```
#version 330 core

in vec2 model;
in uint jointID;

const int MAX_JOINTS = 10;

uniform mat4 joints[MAX_JOINTS];

void main()
{
    gl_Position = joints[jointID] * vec4(model, 0.0f, 1.0f);
}
```

I input some simple data,

```
const GLfloat vertices[] =
{
    // upper arm
    0.0f, 0.0f,
    0.4f, 0.0f,
    0.4f, 0.2f,

    0.0f, 0.0f,
    0.4f, 0.2f,
    0.0f, 0.2f,

    // lower arm
    0.4f, 0.0f,
    0.8f, 0.0f,
    0.8f, 0.2f,

    0.4f, 0.0f,
    0.8f, 0.2f,
    0.4f, 0.2f
};

const GLuint indices[] =
{
    // upper arm
    0,
    1,
    1,

    0,
    1,
    0,

    // lower arm
    1,
    1,
    1,

    1,
    1,
    1
};
```

(The first array containing the vertices and the second array containing the corresponding boneID's.) Oddly, the boneID's never seem too equal 1 because when I make the matrix at index 1 some really funky value, the vertices remain untransformed. This leads me to believe that it is a problem with the way I set up my glVertexAttribPointer's,

```
void SkinnedModel::draw()
{
    shaderProgram.use();

    glEnableVertexAttribArray(modelLoc);
    glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, vertexBuffer);
    glVertexAttribPointer(modelLoc, 2, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, 0, NULL);

    glEnableVertexAttribArray(jointIDLoc);
    glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, indexBuffer);
    glVertexAttribPointer(jointIDLoc, 1, GL_UNSIGNED_INT, GL_FALSE, 0, NULL);

    glUniformMatrix4fv(jointsLoc, 10, GL_FALSE, (GLfloat*)&poseMatrices);

    glDrawArrays(GL_TRIANGLES, 0, numVertices); 

    glDisableVertexAttribArray(modelLoc);
    glDisableVertexAttribArray(jointIDLoc);
}
```

I've been banging my head against the desk for the past few hours looking at what seems to be correct code. Anyway, it's probably something dumb I missed. Any help is appreciated.

Here is all the relevant source code (just in case):

SkinnedModel.h

```
#pragma once

#include "stl/DataTypes.h"
#include "Shader.h"
#include <Dense>

using namespace Eigen;

struct Joint
{
    Joint** children;
    Joint* parent;
    U32 index;
};

class SkinnedModel
{
public:
    static void init();
    static void destroy();

    SkinnedModel();
    ~SkinnedModel();
    void create(const GLfloat* vertices, const GLuint* jointIndices, GLint numVertices, Joint* rootJoint);
    void draw();
    void rotate(Joint* joint, F32 angle, F32 x, F32 y);

    GLuint vertexBuffer;
    GLuint indexBuffer;
    GLint numVertices;
    //GLint numJoints;
    Joint* root;
    Matrix<GLfloat,4,4> poseMatrices[10];

    static ShaderProgram shaderProgram;
    static GLuint modelLoc;
    static GLuint jointIDLoc;
    static GLuint modelViewMatrixLoc;
    static GLuint jointsLoc;
};
```

SkinnedModel.cpp

```
#include "SkinnedModel.h"

ShaderProgram SkinnedModel::shaderProgram;
GLuint SkinnedModel::modelLoc = -1;
GLuint SkinnedModel::jointIDLoc = -1;
GLuint SkinnedModel::modelViewMatrixLoc = -1;
GLuint SkinnedModel::jointsLoc = -1;

void SkinnedModel::init()
{
    ShaderProgramSettings shaderPS;
    shaderPS.loadShader("Skinned.v.glsl", ShaderType::VERTEX);
    shaderPS.loadShader("Skinned.f.glsl", ShaderType::FRAGMENT);
    shaderProgram = shaderPS.create();
    shaderProgram.use();

    modelLoc = shaderProgram.getAttrib("model");
    jointIDLoc = shaderProgram.getAttrib("jointID");
    //modelViewMatrixLoc = shaderProgram.getUniform("modelViewMatrix");
    jointsLoc = shaderProgram.getUniform("joints");
}

void SkinnedModel::destroy()
{
    shaderProgram.destroy();
}

SkinnedModel::SkinnedModel()
{

}

SkinnedModel::~SkinnedModel()
{
    glDeleteBuffers(1, &vertexBuffer);
    glDeleteBuffers(1, &indexBuffer);
}

void SkinnedModel::create(const GLfloat* vertices, const GLuint* jointIndices, GLint numVertices, Joint* rootJoint)
{
    this->numVertices = numVertices;
    this->root = rootJoint;

    for(U32 i=0;i<10;++i)
    {
        poseMatrices[i] = Matrix<GLfloat,4,4>::Identity();
    }
    poseMatrices[1] = Matrix<GLfloat,4,4>::Zero(); // <--- This should mess it up!

    // Creating buffers
    glDeleteBuffers(1, &vertexBuffer);
    glGenBuffers(1, &vertexBuffer);
    glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, vertexBuffer);
    glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, numVertices*2*sizeof(GLfloat), vertices, GL_STATIC_DRAW);

    glDeleteBuffers(1, &indexBuffer);
    glGenBuffers(1, &indexBuffer);
    glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, indexBuffer);
    glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, numVertices*sizeof(GLuint), jointIndices, GL_STATIC_DRAW);
}

void SkinnedModel::draw()
{
    shaderProgram.use();

    glEnableVertexAttribArray(modelLoc);
    glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, vertexBuffer);
    glVertexAttribPointer(modelLoc, 2, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, 0, NULL);

    glEnableVertexAttribArray(jointIDLoc);
    glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, indexBuffer);
    glVertexAttribPointer(jointIDLoc, 1, GL_UNSIGNED_INT, GL_FALSE, 0, NULL);

    glUniformMatrix4fv(jointsLoc, 10, GL_FALSE, (GLfloat*)&poseMatrices);

    glDrawArrays(GL_TRIANGLES, 0, numVertices); 

    glDisableVertexAttribArray(modelLoc);
    glDisableVertexAttribArray(jointIDLoc);
}

void SkinnedModel::rotate(Joint* joint, F32 angle, F32 x, F32 y)
{
    F32 rcos = cos(angle);
    F32 rsin = sin(angle);
    Matrix<GLfloat, 4, 4> rotMatrix = Matrix<GLfloat, 4, 4>::Identity();
    rotMatrix(0,0) = rcos;
    rotMatrix(0,1) = -rsin;
    rotMatrix(1,0) = rsin;
    rotMatrix(1,1) = rcos;
    rotMatrix(0,3) = x-rcos*x+rsin*y;
    rotMatrix(1,3) = y-rsin*x-rcos*y;
    poseMatrices[joint->index] *= rotMatrix;
}
```

Game.cpp

```
void Game::init()
{
    GUI::init();
    SkinnedModel::init();
    getScreen()->setBackgroundColor(1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f);

    const GLfloat vertices[] =
    {
        // upper arm
        0.0f, 0.0f,
        0.4f, 0.0f,
        0.4f, 0.2f,

        0.0f, 0.0f,
        0.4f, 0.2f,
        0.0f, 0.2f,

        // lower arm
        0.4f, 0.0f,
        0.8f, 0.0f,
        0.8f, 0.2f,

        0.4f, 0.0f,
        0.8f, 0.2f,
        0.4f, 0.2f
    };

    const GLuint indices[] =
    {
        // upper arm
        0,
        1,
        1,

        0,
        1,
        0,

        // lower arm
        1,
        1,
        1,

        1,
        1,
        1
    };


    upperArm.parent = 0;
    upperArm.children = new Joint*[1];
    upperArm.children[0] = &lowerArm;
    upperArm.index = 0;

    lowerArm.parent = &upperArm;
    lowerArm.children = 0;
    lowerArm.index = 1;

    m.create(vertices, indices, 12, &upperArm);
    //m.rotate(&lowerArm, PI/4, 0.4f, 0.1f);

    //DEBUG("SIZE %i", sizeof(Eigen::Matrix<GLfloat,4,4>));

}

void Game::loop(double dt)
{
    m.draw();
}
```

**Update:** Apparently if all values for the boneID are set to 1 it never uses 1 in the shader either @.@. So the second array isn't even being read, or it's not being read correctly.

Comment: If you're not sure about some specific value in shader, you can always pass it to output colour (probably will need to rescale to better match visual range).

Comment: Do you call your `rotate` function? Check contents of `poseMatrices` when program enters `draw`. Also, what `x` and `y` supposed to mean in rotate?

Comment: The rotate function is not relevant, I just put it in the class to test at some point. I checked the contents of the matrices, and they are correct. jointID still likes to be 0 for some reason, even when i set all the values to 1 so that it cannot possibly be 0. I also checked the index buffer after it was set and confirmed that everything was correct there as well. The problem is somewhere in the draw call.

Comment: It is relevant because it affects matrices. What is actual values of first two matrices? (add it to question please). Also, there was comment where you said that index is correct, but now it is removed - what was the results?

Comment: The rotate function is irrelevant because I never used it. I removed the comment because the indices are not actually working properly. What I know from testing is that jointID is at some point 0 even if all data is greater than 0. So how data is passed to jointID is what seems to be the problem.

Comment: Btw, the matrices are all initialized to the identity matrix. I've been setting specific matrix index to bogus values however just so I can test if they are being used in the shader.

Comment: I'm not getting it - if matrices all identity, index doesn't change a single thing - they're all equal. But anyway, question in current state is impossible to answer - please make SSCCE (http://www.sscce.org/).

Comment: Why do you call `glDeleteBuffers` in your `create` function?

Comment: @GuyRT So it deletes the previous buffer if it exists, otherwise it does nothing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use `glVertexAttribIPointer` if you are using integer vertex attributes (i.e. something you have declared `in uint` or `in int` etc. in your vertex shader).

replace

```
glVertexAttribPointer(jointIDLoc, 1, GL_UNSIGNED_INT, GL_FALSE, 0, NULL);
```

with

```
glVertexAttribIPointer(jointIDLoc, 1, GL_UNSIGNED_INT, 0, NULL);
```

(note that `glVertexAttribIPointer` doesn't take the *normalized* parameter)